# How to integrate G729 codec in pjsip?

Tags: android, pjsip

I have put G729 library files in my android project but that codec is not shown in GUI.

I have try to find G722 for reference but there are so many files for that.

So can some one help me to get exact location where I have to add code to enable G729?

Any help or suggestion would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps from csipsimple project for android . Get the source code from here 
http://csipsimple.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CSipSimple/jni/g729/

Add the files from pj_sources to pjmedia-codec directory . And follow the steps as other codecs added there as like  g722 .